# Will pregnancy affect my chance of getting the job?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, parental-leave, south-africa

I applied for a position and when I got a call for the first interview o already knew I was about 10 weeks pregnant. I got called back for the second interview (which is in two days). After much deliberation I decided that disclosing my pregnancy was the right thing to do as I want to be upfront and transparent.

I have a friend who works at this company o am applying to, and today she told me that she had learned that my colleague is also applying for this position. Even though I informed my colleague o am applying for this position, he never mentioned to me that he too had applied and that he too had also been to the first interview and was invited to the second round of interviews.

I now feel like I am about to waste my time,spending time working on the presentation and taking off work, when my colleague will stand a better chance than me because he won't be needing maternity leave in a few months. His deception is another issue on its own.

Anyway I live in South Africa, where we have a "BEE" process, which means black people should be considered first before other races. My colleague is black and I am not. Secondly, although there are laws against discrimination of pregnant woman, I am not employed yet by this company so I am not covered in that regard. Also I feel they will probably never list my pregnancy as a reason for not selecting me, but they will simply say my colleague is a better candidate then me... even though I know he is not. Also bear in mind that the job is at a manufacturing plant which will mean I can't be onsite due to fumes etc..

Have I ruined my chance at getting this job by mentioning my pregnancy? How should I bring up my pregnancy in interviews going forward? It pains me to do all this extra work, only to be disappointed :(

Comment: A lot of this is specific to you and the company and the country which would make all our responses most likely opinion based instead of a definitive answer.  Based on what you said it does look like you will be discriminated against, but at the same time the company needs to make money.  If you will be out due to pregnancy and you can't even be at your job before due to the fumes, why would you want to work there?  That part doesn't make sense to me unless you are just getting the job for the benefits, which contradicts your statements about being better qualified...

Comment: @mutt There is no way for this scenario to look like anything other than a pregnant mother-to-be wanting to scoop up benefits at a job she has no intention of keeping after they dry up. Regardless if that's the case or not, that's all any employer will see, and they will use any justification to not hire.

Comment: I am not familiar with South African law - how does maternity leave work where you are?

Comment: Hi Joe S - thanks for the comment. I currently work in industry, so I am familiar with the requirement for pregnant woman in the work place. We are not permitted in the plant during pregnancy for health and safety reasons. I am likely to always work in industry since this is my expertise. Would you hire me?

Comment: when you told them you were pregnant, was there an immediate discussion of this "fumes" issue? Di you talk about where you would work during the pregnancy? Did they react like "no problem, this is super common, you can just xyz" or did they frown and say "well we would have to work out what to do about that"? Focus on that more than the other applicant. There will always be other applicants whether you know them or not. If you think you have no chance or wouldn't want the job anyway for safety reasons, end the process. Otherwise, keep going and treat it as practice.

Comment: @JaneDoe What's wrong with your current position that you're making a change during your pregnancy?

Comment: I will not qualify for paid maternity leave - which is fine, as I can plan properly for this. There are no benefits which are extra here, but naturally with any job applied for, they need to match or better my current salary. Had I not been pregnant I would have more confidence.

Comment: It's concerning that you are doing "so much work" for an interview.  Maybe that's the basic problem here.  It's perhaps worth noting that you lead with "I urgently need advice."...... as I understand it, this site is really down on "advice".  It's a QA site.  It's difficult to see what your actual question is. You know?

Comment: Unless there are laws against it, and even then, some people will not hire you because of that. But the only way to find out is to try.

Comment: Honestly, in a competition between (in your example) a black man and a white pregnant woman, if either got the job, the other one could complain about discrimination. The best you can do is to try to ignore this issue (and your colleague's secretiveness) and focus on showing off your skills at the interview/presentation. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

There is a considerable chance that the person who knows about your pregnacy won't be the only person deciding about hiring. So there is a chance he or she would not tell anyone else. This is highly culture-specific - I personally would not discuss about candidate's pregnacy or health unless some very specific circumstances.

There is also a chance that you are simply the best candidate and even if people who decide know, they will hire you.

My advice is to proceed. You have nothing to lose apart of some effort and time.

Comment: I appreciate the comments! I have decided to give it my best regardless of whether I'm pregnant.